# How do I set selected value that is base on drop-down list in Jquery and assign it to my model?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I need the value from the option to be assigned to my model once the user clicks on the specific option.

```
<select name="isEmailVerified" class="form-select">
                                <option value="" selected> all </option>
                                <option value="true"> verified </option>
                                <option value="false"> unverified </option>
                            </select>
```

expected value => @Model.IsEmailVerified.XXXXX(my value)

Comment: `@Model.IsEmailVerified` is written in the page. Do you hope that after you select an item, the value of isEmailVerified displayed somewhere on the page will show the value you just selected? Or do you just want to send the selected value to the backend? Can you show more details about your expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do when I want to asyncronously send data back and forth is this:

1. I take advantage of Tag Helpers as they're great and saves you a ton of boilerplate code, so I create a standard `<form>` element **without** an actual `Submit` button, just a `div` that looks like one. You might want to check official MSDN Documentation for the [Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper) to create an appropriate model.

   ```
   @model VerificationModel

   <form asp-action="CheckEmail" method="post">
     <select asp-for="IsEmailVerified" asp-items="Model.VerificationTypes">
    <div id="SubmitCheck" class="btn">Check email</div>
   </form>
   ```
2. Create a javascript function that takes care of the actual submitting chore. Since the form is created with the Tag Helpers, the request body will automatically bind

   ```
   $('#SubmitCheck').on('click', function() {
     let form = $(this).parents('form')[0];
     let formData = new FormData(form);

     let request = function () {
       return fetch(form.getAttribute('action'), {
         method: 'POST',
         body: formData
       });
     };

     let onresponse = function() {
       // do some preliminary actions on 200 response
     }

     let callback = function() {
       // deal with response result
     }

     let onerror = function() {
       // deal with errors
     }

     request()
      .then(response => onresponse())
      .then(result => callback())
      .fail(err => onerror());
   })
   ```
3. Add the `[FromForm]` attribute to Controller props (model is the same used in the page) to ensure model binding

   ```
   public async Task<CustomResultClass> CheckEmail([FromForm] VerificationModel model)
   { 
      // do something
   }
   ```